# Composer: how to get <directory> parameter from `create-project` command in post-create-project-cmd script?

Tags: php, composer-php

### Scenario

In order to provide a re-usable theme to downstream projects, I'm building a skeleton package so that I can install it and find-replace various elements to customize it for my projects.
For example, I'm building a project called "example_project", and I include the skeleton into my project, then find-and-replace all "SKELETON_blah" placeholders with "example_project_blah".

### Method

I've defined an upstream package, and am grabbing it into my project using `composer create-project example/skeleton example_root/path/to/example_project_blah`.

I'm using a post-create-project-cmd script to do the placeholder replacement.

### Problem

I can't find a straightforward way to find the project that was created, specifically I want the path `example_root/path/to/example_project_blah`.

`Composer\Script\Event::getArguments()` returns an empty array.

Do I have to go to the ARGV global to get this? Is there a way to get it from the composer event or something more reasonable?

Comment: Can you try dumping the first parameter sent to your even: `$event->getComposer()->getConfig()`? For instance, the `vendor` folder should be discoverable via `$event->getComposer()->getConfig()->get('vendor-dir')`

Comment: Yes, i've done that and dug pretty deep into all the accessible properties and methods. I thought `getIO()` would be a good place to find it, but that only provides an interactive console, not the input from the command.

Comment: It doesn't appear that this is straightforward at all, at least as far as I can tell. Symfony Flex does what you are trying to do, and if you look at their [`.env` dumper](https://github.com/symfony/flex/blob/3e8d6c423092ca89dd8fb998ddb9d7a91139e52f/src/Command/DumpEnvCommand.php#L51) you'll see a call to `root-dir` however that's something [they created](https://github.com/symfony/flex/blob/059f763e64f38d1e540607b1e47b5bd8c53b8973/src/Flex.php#L901) that defaults to `.` Then again, you might just be able to just assume that `.` is the current folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script to rename the original package name with the newly created project's directory name:

```
"post-create-project-cmd": [
  "sed -i -e \"s/original-name/${PWD##*/}/g\" composer.json .gitignore"
]
```

This example would search & replace inside the `composer.json` and `.gitignore` files, repacing `original-name` with the project directory (while also keeping the same package namespace).